# Php how to upgrade your upload size

Tags: php, mysql, upload, size

I have builded CMS but when i upload a file bigger then 1.000kB i get this error:

> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: MySQL server has gone away in               C:\Users\Stefan\Desktop\UsbWebserver\root\Windvogel\bestand_toevoegen.php on line 40
>   Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Error reading result set's header in C:\Users\Stefan\Desktop\UsbWebserver\root\Windvogel\bestand_toevoegen.php on line 40
>   Error! Niet gelukt het bestand te uploaden

Anybody know how i can upload bigger files?
Something like upgrade my upload size or something.
The i want to upload a bigger file in to a blob(mediumblob) file of my database.

Comment: Search for `max_upload_size` in `php.ini` and change it to your required value.

Answer (score 0):

change the following in your php.ini

```
  upload_max_filesize = 10M;
  post_max_size = 20M;
  memory_limit = 20M;
```

This is how it is done if the issue is with php.
But,I think you need to change title of your question, the question seems to be about mysql issue, not php one

Comment: @Stefan did you restart apache after that?

Comment: Yes i restarted it, and with the memory_limit, doesnt make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing up two possible problems.
the first is the post or upload size you can change in php.ini or apache conf for a site
and the next is the package size (result size) in mysql. This setting is changeable in my.cnf

all the best.

ps: too find out whats the real problem we should know what you are doing with the uploaded data or posted data.

Comment: The problem is the upload data, i can echo my data from a big file.

Comment: This is what i do :$query = "
     INSERT INTO `windvaan` (
      `name`, `mime`, `size`, `data`, `created`
     )
     VALUES (
      '{$name}', '{$mime}', {$size}, '{$data}', NOW()
     )";
   
    // Query uitvoeren
    $result = mysql_query($query, $con);